# I need to add an old drive to a new Linux install

Tags: linux

I am in the middle of upgrading my Linux server.  The last step will require me to add the existing disk to the new server.  So the existing disk will have a /root /home, etc.  Will this screw Linux up?  I will make sure to boot from the correct disk.  Will I be able to mount the "old" drive under a different path?

Just to be clear, there is a new disk with /root, /home, etc.  I just need to get the files off of the old disk.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: No, it won' t screw anything up. `# mkdir /mnt/old`. Then mount the old root partition as `/mnt/old`  (e.g. `# mount /dev/sdx5 /mnt/old`) and then mount any separate partitions (like the old `/home/` under `/mnt/old/home`) You new system will not care and you are doing nothing more than mounting partitions under a mountpoint somewhere on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mounted your disk to a directory which already contains data this data will be hidden until removing the mount.

So to keep your data safe you can create a new directory and mount the disk to it.